# Postgresql 9.3 GROUP BY on an indexed column in 30m rows table taking a long time

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, query-performance

I have a simple table which holds GPS data for various vehicles with 30 million rows.

```
         Column         |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                     | bigint                      | not null  | plain    |              |
 equipmentid            | bigint                      |           | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "some_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "some_idx" btree (equipmentid)
```

The table has more columns, but in my opinion they are not revelant for my question (but if you think they are let me know and I'll add them).

I'm trying to obtain the last GPS position for each equipment like so:

```
user=> explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select max(gps2.id) from GpsData gps2 group by gps2.equipmentId;
                                                                                           QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=0.56..131266837.64 rows=298 width=16) (actual time=64679.945..637667.147 rows=307 loops=1)
   Output: max(id), equipmentid
   Buffers: shared hit=5662655 read=11225117
   ->  Index Scan using some_idx on public.gpsdata gps2  (cost=0.56..131099834.76 rows=33399980 width=16) (actual time=35.452..634355.329 rows=29176300 loops=1)
         Output: equipmentid, id
         Buffers: shared hit=5662655 read=11225117
 Total runtime: 637677.321 ms
(7 rows)
```

As you can see this query runs in more than 5 minutes, which is an awful lot. It also seems to me that this is one of the most simple use-cases for a `GROUP BY` (i.e. I expect it to be much faster).

I'm trying to look at the analysis, but... I don't know where to begin. I mean it does say `rows=29176300`, which looks like a lot of rows, but still 5 mins seems excessive.

I should also note that I've forced an index scan via  `SET enable_seqscan = off` hoping it would be faster, but I was wrong (I had `Seq Scan` instead of index scan in my output before; it used to take around 4 minutes which is slightly less)

Any hints for me on where to start? My postgres version is `PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit`.

**Edit:** Some more info, as requested.

```
user=> select pg_total_relation_size('some_idx');
 pg_total_relation_size
------------------------
             1620033536
(1 row)
```

Comment: Maybe your harddisk is simply slow. A total of 11225117 blocks were read from the index which is about 85 GB.

Comment: That would be strange, considering that my HDD has 45GB in total (or maybe info was read multiple times?)

Comment: Please see edit above (it returns the value `1620033536`).

Comment: Hmm, strange. With this test setup: http://dpaste.com/1DNQWWW I get this execution plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/5QWR (Using 9.3) Even with a Seq Scan, 30 million rows only account for 461573 blocks. Does a `vacuum full gpsdata;` change anything?

Comment: With an index on `gpsdata  (equipmentid,id)` the above setup gets down to 6 seconds.

Comment: Well, that's interesting; `vacuum full gpsdata` indeed dropped the time to under 10 seconds.
But... is this constant, or should I expect that in 1month or so I'll have to perform the same operation? (will try the composed index idea slightly later and get back to you)

Comment: There were 90k rows inserted yesterday (and similar each day); there were 2-3 days where around 20m in total, rows, were inserted (data import), but I've rebuilt the indexes afterwards (should this help?).
P.S. Can you make your comments into an answer? It might help someone else. Especially the auto vacuum explanations; I for one didn't knew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the number of buffers it took to read the index, you are probably suffering from table and index [bloat](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat).

If you can afford to lock the table, run `vacuum full analyze gpsdata` to clean up old data.

There are several possible reasons why [auto-vacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html) did not take care of cleaning up properly and re-using deleted space:

1. You have many sessions accessing that table that are in the state "idle in transaction". Rows that are used by a transaction can't be cleaned up. Make sure you properly commit all transactions - that includes `SELECT` statement which also start a transaction. 
    The easiest way to do that is to enable autocommit (default in `psql`)
2. You have a high frequency of updates on that table so that the table is constantly changed and auto-vacuum can't keep up (or doesn't get a chance to clean up - see 1.)
3. you have disabled auto-vacuum

---

An index on `gpsdata (equipmentid,id)` might speed up the calculation.

Comment: That was it, thanks; will look if this happens again, and then if so (and probably WILL happen), I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Andrei: (auto-)vacuum can be a real PITA - it's one of the most annoying things in Postgres. In 90% of the time it works just fine - but it's those 10% that are annoying ;)